# There does not exist a $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, independent of $\theta$, such that $\int_{0}^{1/\theta}g(x) \text{ d}x= 1$ for all $\theta > 0$

Tags: probability, integration, machine-learning

This is an intermediate step to a stats problem I have:

> Show that there does not exist a $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such
>   that $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1/\theta}g(x) \text{ d}x = 1$ for all $\theta > 0$. (**Please note that $g$ cannot depend on $\theta$.**)

I thought of assuming that $g$ is continuous, so thus $g\left(\dfrac{1}{\theta}\right) = 0$ (after taking derivatives of both sides). But I'm not sure what I can do with this.

If more context is needed, please let me know.

Comment: So $g$ is assumed to have no $\theta$ in it?

Comment: This doesn't really make sense as written. For a *fixed* $\theta$, of course such a $g$ exists - take $g(x) = \theta$ for all $x$. If you want this for *all* $\theta$, then it should be pretty easy to prove that $g \equiv 0$, and get a contradiction.

Comment: @Shashi Yes, I'm about to clarify that. Thanks.

Comment: @user296602 I've clarified the question. Thanks.

Comment: You assume that $g$ is continuos then indeed it is trivial. But the question remains for the general case...

Comment: In the sense of distributions there is an answer:  $g(x)=2\delta (x)$, the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).  Despite its name, it is not a function.

Comment: Do you know measure theory? Have you been introduced to Riemann integration? If the answer on both of these questions are not affirmative then your assumption on $f$ sounds reasonable, and subsequently, your solution looks good.

Comment: @clark Don't know measure theory, but I do know Riemann integration from intro real analysis.

Comment: If you assume that $g$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,a]$, then $g$ should be bounded, by definition. Assume  then $  |g(x)|\leq M  $ for all $x\in [0,a]$. Then pick $\theta =2/M$. For that $\theta $, \begin{align} \int _{0}^{M/2} g(x) \text {d} x &\leq \int _{0}^{M/2} |g(x)| \text {d} x\\ &\leq \int _{0}^{M/2} M\text {d} x\\ &\leq \int _{0}^{M/2} M\text {d} x=1/2, \end{align} a contradiction.

Comment: @clark Clever. I haven't seen real analysis with integrals in... at least 3 years now, but I was actually able to follow that. Please feel free to put that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's prove that **no (Lebesgue) integrable function** $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ can exist.

Let $\alpha=\frac{1}{\theta}>0$. We have:
\begin{align}
\int^\alpha_0 g(x)\,dx = 1
\end{align}
for all $\alpha>0$. Now take $1\geq\alpha>0$ then:
\begin{align}
\int^{1}_0 g(x)\, dx = 1 , \ \ \ \ \int^{\alpha}_0 g(x)\, dx = 1 
\end{align}
Substracting both from each other yields:
\begin{align}
\int^{1}_{\alpha} g(x)\,dx = 0
\end{align}
Take $f_n(x) = \mathbf{1}_{[\frac{1}{n}, 1]}g(x)$ and this function converges pointwise to $\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}g(x)$. Clearly $$\int_0^1 f_n(x)\,dx=\int_{1/n}^1 f_n(x)\,dx=\int_{1/n}^1 g(x)\,dx=0$$ 
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. But we have:
\begin{align}
1=  \int_0^1 g(x)\,dx = \int_0^{1} \lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)\,dx = \lim_{n\to\infty}\int^1_0 f_n(x)\,dx = 0
\end{align}
by [The Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem). Hence a contradiction: no Lebesgue integrable function can exist. No Riemann integrable function can exist either since Riemann integrability implies Lebesgue integrability.